# MS Flow - notify users by mail on new file, but not for newly-created, empty files

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I am quite new with Microsoft Flow and although I understand the building blocks, I still experience a - possibly newbie - problem.

I have created a Flow which emails users when a new file is created, uploaded or edited in a certain folder on Sharepoint. This is a very basic flow, which is even available as a template.

The issue I'm experiencing is that for newly created documents, the flow sends out a notification that is essentially worthless:
"A new file has been created on Sharepoint: NewDocument.docx"

Moreover, it happens that a file is uploaded to Sharepoint in that folder and is consequently moved outside that folder or renamed to something else, resulting in more useless notifications.

How would I change this template such that only a notification is sent out when the user is actually done editing the file?

Is there a way such that I can manually approve each sent-notification, or would it be better to automate based on last-edited time. The latter solution would result in very long flow runtimes, which definitely is not ideal.

Some time ago I tried a simple sleep that waits 1 hour before notifying, but I noticed the information did not update and even though the document was already renamed, the notification still used the initial naming scheme of a new document.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: how about making some checks before sending the mail? I mean, you can allways query for the item linked to the event and make some checks.

Comment: Can I requery the item? Is there an easy way to do that? I suppose I could continuously check for some conditions to be met, but would that not result in a long flow runtime?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, you don't have to run a query. Once the flow has fired, you should have all the document properties by default, just use the condition box to ask for the propertie you want to check. In my case it was quite easy as my library had a custom document type so the document is created as "document type" by default and then, when saved, is saved with the custom content type... So I "only" had to ask for the content type to be different from "document"

Comment: Ah okay. my library does not, sadly. I suppose it would not make sense from a design perspective to change the document type purely for this problem right?
Once a flow is fired, are the document properties static or do they update if the file updates in the meantime? If it is static, I am not sure how I would tackle this properly as I then need to use a flow for edited files, but that would kinda mess with the semantics of the notification...

Comment: it's static. But the event will fire back again when the user or the upload updates the file to have its name. You could check for the filename or any required columns. I know this is not the best thing just throwing ideas to help you out.

Comment: Ah okay. And the event will fire again since my flow also handles "edited files" right? Or is there some hidden mechanism to uploaded/created files? Regardless, thanks for your help! Sharepoint/Flow is sometimes very confusing...

Comment: Yup! That's it... The event will fire again. IMHO, although this behavior is by design, it's a pretty shady experience